# Magento- Page not redirected to success page after submit order via authorize.net payment

Tags: magento, payment, checkout, authorize.net, orders

We are getting an issue in some of our store orders which had their transactions via authorize.net. We saw a strange behavior  in getting  their transactions. The customer which was ordering, was not redirected to success page but instead was shown the error.  Because of this misconception, the customer ordered twice. So, a double transaction was placed due to the issue. In the ‘payment.log’ file in server of magento site,  it shows ‘Ok’ message in the response but there is a difference of  around 12 seconds in request and response.
The transaction did placed in authorize.net site and order has processing status in magento 2 admin.

The payment.log request response:

```
[2018-10-22 15:31:54] main.DEBUG: array (
'request' => 
array (
'x_version' => '3.1',
'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
'x_test_request' => 'FALSE',
'x_login' => '****',
'x_method' => 'CC',
'x_relay_url' => 'https://www.blazingglass.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
'x_type' => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
'x_fp_sequence' => '1375',
'x_invoice_num' => '000000649',
'x_amount' => 736.0,
'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
'x_tax' => '0.00',
'x_freight' => '0.00',
'x_first_name' => 'Paul',
'x_last_name' => 'Noonan',
'x_company' => '',
'x_address' => '5 Oweno Place',
'x_city' => 'MAHWAH',
'x_state' => 'New Jersey',
'x_zip' => '07430',
'x_country' => 'US',
'x_phone' => '2013208170',
'x_fax' => '',
'x_cust_id' => '',
'x_customer_ip' => '74.105.126.33',
'x_customer_tax_id' => '',
'x_email' => 'luap5595@aol.com',
'x_email_customer' => '0',
'x_merchant_email' => '',
'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'Paul',
'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Noonan',
'x_ship_to_company' => '',
'x_ship_to_address' => '5 Oweno Place',
'x_ship_to_city' => 'MAHWAH',
'x_ship_to_state' => 'New Jersey',
'x_ship_to_zip' => '07430',
'x_ship_to_country' => 'US',
'x_po_num' => '',
'x_fp_timestamp' => 1540222314,
'x_fp_hash' => '74baf11480c3ebcdff67993ce1010a68',
),
) [] []
[2018-10-22 15:32:07] main.DEBUG: array (
'response' => 
array (
'x_response_code' => '1',
'x_response_reason_code' => '1',
'x_response_reason_text' => 'This transaction has been approved.',
'x_avs_code' => 'Y',
'x_auth_code' => '294912',
'x_trans_id' => '41011978127',
'x_method' => 'CC',
'x_card_type' => 'American Express',
'x_account_number' => 'XXXX3002',
'x_first_name' => 'Paul',
'x_last_name' => 'Noonan',
'x_company' => '',
'x_address' => '5 Oweno Place',
'x_city' => 'MAHWAH',
'x_state' => 'New Jersey',
'x_zip' => '07430',
'x_country' => 'US',
'x_phone' => '2013208170',
'x_fax' => '',
'x_email' => 'luap5595@aol.com',
'x_invoice_num' => '000000649',
'x_description' => '',
'x_type' => 'auth_capture',
'x_cust_id' => '',
'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'Paul',
'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Noonan',
'x_ship_to_company' => '',
'x_ship_to_address' => '5 Oweno Place',
'x_ship_to_city' => 'MAHWAH',
'x_ship_to_state' => 'New Jersey',
'x_ship_to_zip' => '07430',
'x_ship_to_country' => 'US',
'x_amount' => '736.00',
'x_tax' => '0.00',
'x_duty' => '0.00',
'x_freight' => '0.00',
'x_tax_exempt' => 'FALSE',
'x_po_num' => '',
'x_MD5_Hash' => '0B8AB4D90541777A4A199520774DC414',
'x_SHA2_Hash' => '',
'x_cvv2_resp_code' => 'M',
'x_cavv_response' => '',
'x_test_request' => 'false',
'controller_action_name' => 'directpost_payment',
'is_secure' => '1',
),
) [] []
```